# JavaScript library/framework to extract text from HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js

We are recently working on the development of a crawler. One major feature/function is to do transformation from crawled HTML into text. We have surveyed a few python solution such as [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html). However, we decide to move coding language from python to nodejs (Because of the [headless chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)). Is there any recommendation on exist JS framework/library excellent to do the work in transforming html into text? (e.g.: [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text))

**Ps.** It will be great that the package/library itself can have some intelligence to remove the advertisement/footer/header out and easy to do extension if we want customized logic.

Many thanks!

Comment: What text do you want to extract? <HEAD> metadata keywords? Page title?

Comment: Hi  Nicolas Raoul, We wish to extract the title/body of page. Take URL=`https://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-popular-programming-languages-developers-should-learn-in-2019/` for example, we wish to extract text including title '10 popular programming languages developers should learn in 2019' and the article body. But it is ok that the library/framework not that smart/intelligent. But it is great that it knows to remove header/footer/banner and advertisement will be good enough!

Comment: A classic non-javascript solution would also be `"lynx --dump  http://example.com"` (just to have something to benchmark against).

Comment: Hi knb , Got it! Many thanks for your suggestion. Good to know (lynx as 'a customizable text-based web browser')!